# Firefox OS App (timer) Background Execution

Tags: javascript, mobile, firefox-os

I'm developing a Pomodoro Timer app for Firefox OS and I'm having a problem with the execution of it:
Once the timer is running **the execution is suspended every time the phone goes in low power mode** (which is quite typical in my scenario, for the timer runs for 25mins) **and is resumed only when the screen is turned on again**.

I searched for a way to prevent this, and according to Mozilla docs there are two APIs ([Power Management](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/WebAPI/Power_Management) and [Idle](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/WebAPI/Idle)) by which you could either:

- Prevent the screen from turning off
- Be notified when the app goes in low power mode

Unfortunately these APIs are available only for [certified apps](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Firefox_OS/Security/Security_model#Trusted_and_Untrusted_Apps) (the ones shipped with the phone), which basically means you can't use them if you want to publish your app.

Is any of you having the same problem or have a hint on how to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Privileged apps can use navigator.requestWakeLock.

```
navigator.requestWakeLock("cpu");
```

App will never suspend even if the screen is turned off.

[Background services API](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Webapi) is better, but not implemented yet.

Answer (score 2):

have you tried to use [Worker](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Worker) API ?