# Implement service on Firefox OS

Tags: firefox, mozilla, firefox-os

I'm quite new to **Firefox OS**. At the moment I'm struggling with implementing some kind of service that listens for `geolocation` updates in the background.
If there are lots of apps running at the same time mine seems to be killed. While debugging with **App Manager** it disconnects silently.

I tried `requestWakeLock('cpu')` and the use of a Worker (as proposed in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21284418/firefox-os-app-timer-background-execution)) but without success.
Background services API isn't implemented, yet and will be available for certified apps only.

I know that there are non-certified apps like `ConnectA2` that stay alive all the time so there has to be a way.

Could anybody give me a hint?

Answer (score 1):

Firefox OS doesn't provide a way for you to run a service in the background intentionally, since the classes of the devices that we target (for example, the 128MB device) won't be able to support running apps constantly in the background.

There are alternate ways of implementing these kinds of services though.  For example you can use the [mozAlarm API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator.mozAlarms) in order to wake up your application at specific intervals, or you can use the [SimplePush API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/WebAPI/Simple_Push) which allows you to notify your app when a remote server initiates an event.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Alarm API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Alarm_API) to prevent your app to be killed in the background.
Alarms wakes up the app at fixed intervals.

```
var alarmId = 0;
function setAlarm() {
    function onAlarmAdded() {
        alarmId = request.result;
    }
    var alarmDate = new Date(Date.now() + (60 * 1000)); // 60 seconds later
    var request = navigator.mozAlarms.add(alarmDate, "ignoreTimezone");
    request.onsuccess = onAlarmAdded;
}
function setHandler() {
    function onAlarm(mozAlarm) {
        // set next alarm
        setAlarm();
    }
    navigator.mozSetMessageHandler("alarm", onAlarm);
}
function startAlarm() {
    setHandler();
    setAlarm();
}
function stopAlarm() {
    navigator.mozAlarms.remove(alarmId);
}
```